# Dismiss the keyboard in uiwebview in case I d'ont want to submit the form

Tags: ios, button, uiwebview, cordova, keyboard

I am developing a application in phonegap. In the app, there is a page which contains two textfields and a image. No submit button because I don't want to submit the form. the desired working is as follow..

1. the user taps the text fields, the keyboard appears.
2. clicking on the image below calls a javascript(jquery method-> $.post()) function which picks the data from the textfields and send it to server(json). that means I m not submitting the form.

and the go button on the virtual keyboard is supposed to submit the form. But in my case as I m not submitting the form so go button doesn't work and it doesn't look appropriate.

I want to get rid of the button..either it may dismiss the keyboard or call the jquery function which it is not supporting.

I searched a lot over the net. I came to know that if i remove the form tag the go button changes to return button which really worked then the return button again looks dumb.

So please help me to get rid of either of the button(preferably the return button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to get rid off the button. What you could do instead, is to have the input field in form with and onsubmit event. This event should perform the jquery $.post method and return false to prevent standard form submission. This way your go button would actually work the way user expects and you don't have to disable it.